# Почему у меня не показывает нумерация не показывается в QPlainTextEdit в PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5, pyqt

> вот файл

```
import sys 
import un
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import Qt


class LineNumberArea(Qt.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, editor):
        super().__init__(editor)
        self.myeditor = editor

        def sizeHint(self):
        return Qt.QSize(self.myeditor.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0)

       def paintEvent(self, event):
           self.myeditor.lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(event)


class CodeEditor(Qt.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button = QCommandLinkButton('Desing', self)
        self.button.setStyleSheet('border: 0px; padding: 0px;')
        self.button.setCursor(Qt.Qt.ArrowCursor)
        self.button.resize(91, 40)

        self.setStyleSheet("""font-family:'Consolas';
            color:#ccc; 
            font-size: 20px;
            background-color:#2b2b2b;""")

        self.lineNumberArea = LineNumberArea(self)

        self.blockCountChanged[int].connect(self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth)
        self.updateRequest[Qt.QRect,int].connect(self.updateLineNumberArea)
        self.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.highlightCurrentLine)

        self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth()

        self.completer = un.MyCompleter()
        self.completer.setWidget(self)
        self.completer.insertText.connect(self.insertCompletion)

        def insertCompletion(self, completion):
        tc = self.textCursor()
        extra = (len(completion) - len(self.completer.completionPrefix()))
        tc.movePosition(QTextCursor.Left)
        tc.movePosition(QTextCursor.EndOfWord)
        tc.insertText(completion[-extra:])
        self.setTextCursor(tc)
        self.completer.popup().hide()

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        if self.completer:
            self.completer.setWidget(self)
        QPlainTextEdit.focusInEvent(self, event)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):

        tc = self.textCursor()
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Tab and self.completer.popup().isVisible():
            self.completer.insertText.emit(self.completer.getSelected())
            self.completer.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.PopupCompletion)
        return

        QPlainTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event)
        tc.select(QTextCursor.WordUnderCursor)
        cr = self.cursorRect()

        if len(tc.selectedText()) > 0:
            self.completer.setCompletionPrefix(tc.selectedText())
            popup = self.completer.popup()
            popup.setCurrentIndex(self.completer.completionModel().index(0, 0))

            cr.setWidth(self.completer.popup().sizeHintForColumn(0)
                    + self.completer.popup().verticalScrollBar().sizeHint().width())
            self.completer.complete(cr)
        else:
            self.completer.popup().hide()


    def lineNumberAreaWidth(self):
        digits = 1
        count = max(1, self.blockCount())
        while count >= 10:
            count   /= 10
            digits  +=  1
       space = 3 + self.fontMetrics().width('9') * digits
       return space


    def updateLineNumberAreaWidth(self):
        self.setViewportMargins(self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0, 0, 0)


    def updateLineNumberArea(self, rect, dy):

        if dy:
            self.lineNumberArea.scroll(0, dy)
        else:
            self.lineNumberArea.update(0, rect.y(), self.lineNumberArea.width(),
                   rect.height())

        if rect.contains(self.viewport().rect()):
            self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth()


    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
    
        cr = self.contentsRect();
        self.lineNumberArea.setGeometry(Qt.QRect(cr.left(), cr.top(),
                self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), cr.height()))
   
   
    def lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(self, event):
        mypainter = Qt.QPainter(self.lineNumberArea)

        mypainter.setBackground(Qt.QColor(Qt.Qt.green))

        mypainter.setFont(Qt.QFont("", 15))

        mypainter.fillRect(event.rect(), Qt.Qt.lightGray)

        block = self.firstVisibleBlock()
        blockNumber = block.blockNumber()
        top = self.blockBoundingGeometry(block).translated(self.contentOffset()).top()
        bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()

        height = self.fontMetrics().height()
        while block.isValid() and (top <= event.rect().bottom()):
            if block.isVisible() and (bottom >= event.rect().top()):
                number = str(blockNumber + 1)
                mypainter.setPen(Qt.Qt.black)
                mypainter.drawText(0, int(top), self.lineNumberArea.width(), height,
                Qt.Qt.AlignRight, number)

            block  = block.next()
            top    = bottom
            bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()
            blockNumber += 1


    def highlightCurrentLine(self):
        extraSelections = []

        if not self.isReadOnly():
            selection = Qt.QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()

            #Qt.Qt.green

            lineColor = Qt.QColor('#2d2d2d').lighter(160)

            selection.format.setBackground(lineColor)
            selection.format.setProperty(Qt.QTextFormat.FullWidthSelection, True)
            selection.cursor = self.textCursor()
            selection.cursor.clearSelection()
            extraSelections.append(selection)
        self.setExtraSelections(extraSelections)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        buttonSize = self.button.sizeHint()
        frameWidth = self.style().pixelMetric(QStyle.PM_DefaultFrameWidth)
        print(buttonSize.width(), buttonSize.height(), frameWidth)
        #print(self.rect().right() - frameWidth - buttonSize.width() - buttonSize.height())
        #print((self.rect().bottom() - buttonSize.height() + 1) / 2)
        #print(self.rect().bottom() - buttonSize.height() - buttonSize.width() + 1)
        #print(self.rect().bottom(), self.rect().right())
        self.button.move(int(self.rect().right() - 111), 2)
        super(CodeEditor, self).resizeEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)

    txt = CodeEditor()
    #txt.buttonClicked.connect(text2_clic)
    highlight = un.PythonHighlighter(txt.document())
    infile = open('un.py', 'r')
    txt.setPlainText(infile.read())
    txt.setStyleSheet("""font-family:'Consolas'; 
       color: #ccc; 
       font-size: 20px;
       background-color: #2b2b2b;""")
    txt.setGeometry(400, 100, 600, 400)
    txt.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

> вот файл un.py

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

def format(color, style=''):
     """ Верните QTextCharFormat с указанными атрибутами. """
    _color = QColor()
    _color.setNamedColor(color)

    _format = QTextCharFormat()
    _format.setForeground(_color)
    if 'bold' in style:
        _format.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
    if 'italic' in style:
        _format.setFontItalic(True)

return _format


# Синтаксические стили, которые могут использоваться
STYLES = {
    'moduls' : format('lime'),
    'keyword': format('cyan'),
    #'func': format('cyan'),
    'operator': format('white'),
    'brace': format('darkGray'),
    'defclass': format('cyan'),
    'string': format('yellow'),
    'string2': format('yellow'),
    'comment': format('green'),
    #'permen': format('greenyellow'),
    #'permenposle': format('cyan'),
    'self': format('orange'),
    'numbers': format('purple'),
    }


class PythonHighlighter (QSyntaxHighlighter):
      """Синтаксические маркеры для языка Python. """
    # Python keywords
    import sys
    moduls = []

    for i in sys.stdlib_module_names:
        moduls.append(i)



    keywords = ['and', 'assert', 'break', 'class', 'continue', 'def',
          'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'exec', 'finally',
          'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import', 'in',
          'is', 'lambda', 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'print',
          'raise', 'return', 'try', 'while', 'yield',
          'None', 'True', 'False']



    # Python operators
    operators = [
        '=',
        # Comparison
        '==', '!=', '<', '<=', '>', '>=',
        # Arithmetic
        '\+', '-', '\*', '/', '//', '\%', '\*\*',
        # In-place
        '\+=', '-=', '\*=', '/=', '\%=',
        # Bitwise
        '\^', '\|', '\&', '\~', '>>', '<<',
       ]

    # Python braces
    braces = [
        '\{', '\}', '\(', '\)', '\[', '\]',
    ]
    def __init__(self, document):
        QSyntaxHighlighter.__init__(self, document)

        self.tri_single = (QRegExp("'''"), 1, STYLES['string'])
        self.tri_double = (QRegExp('"""'), 2, STYLES['string2'])

        rules = []

        # Keyword, operator, and brace rules
        rules += [(r'\b%s\b' % w, 0, STYLES['keyword'])
            for w in PythonHighlighter.keywords]
        rules += [(r'\b%s\b' % w, 0, STYLES['moduls'])
            for w in PythonHighlighter.moduls]
        rules += [(r'%s' % o, 0, STYLES['operator'])
            for o in PythonHighlighter.operators]
        rules += [(r'%s' % b, 0, STYLES['brace'])
            for b in PythonHighlighter.braces]

        # All other rules
        rules += [
            (r'\bself\b', 0, STYLES['self']),
            #(r'\bself\b', 0, STYLES['self']),
            (r'"[^"\\]*(\\.[^"\\]*)*"', 0, STYLES['string']),
            (r"'[^'\\]*(\\.[^'\\]*)*'", 0, STYLES['string']),
            (r'\bdef\b\s*(\w+)', 1, STYLES['defclass']),
            (r'\bclass\b\s*(\w+)', 1, STYLES['defclass']),
            (r'#[^\n]*', 0, STYLES['comment']),
            #(r"=[^'\\]*(\\.[^'\\]*)*", 0, STYLES['permenposle']),
            #(r'=[^"\\]*(\\.[^"\\]*)*', 0, STYLES['permenposle']),
            #(r'\.[^\n]*\s*(\w+)', 0, STYLES['func']),
            #(r'[^"\\\.]*(\\.[^"\\\.]*)*=', 0, STYLES['permen']),
            #(r'(.[^(from)|(if)])*\.', 1, STYLES['permen']),
            (r'\b[+-]?[0-9]+[lL]?\b', 0, STYLES['numbers']),
            (r'\b[+-]?0[xX][0-9A-Fa-f]+[lL]?\b', 0, STYLES['numbers']),
        (r'\b[+-]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?:[eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?\b',0, STYLES['numbers']),
     ]

        # Создайте QRegExp для каждого шаблона
        self.rules = [(QRegExp(pat), index, fmt)
            for (pat, index, fmt) in rules]


    def highlightBlock(self, text):
        """Применить выделение синтаксиса к данному блоку текста. """

        # Сделайте другое форматирование синтаксиса
        for expression, nth, format in self.rules:
            index = expression.indexIn(text, 0)
            while index >= 0:
                index  = expression.pos(nth)
                length = len(expression.cap(nth))
                self.setFormat(index, length, format)
                index = expression.indexIn(text, index + length)

        self.setCurrentBlockState(0)

        # Многострочные строки
        in_multiline = self.match_multiline(text, *self.tri_single)
        if not in_multiline:
            in_multiline = self.match_multiline(text, *self.tri_double)

    def match_multiline(self, text, delimiter, in_state, style):
        if self.previousBlockState() == in_state:
            start = 0
            add = 0
        else:
            start = delimiter.indexIn(text)
            add = delimiter.matchedLength()

        while start >= 0:
            end = delimiter.indexIn(text, start + add)
            if end >= add:
                length = end - start + add + delimiter.matchedLength()
                self.setCurrentBlockState(0)
            else:
                self.setCurrentBlockState(in_state)
                length = len(text) - start + add

            self.setFormat(start, length, style)
            start = delimiter.indexIn(text, start + length)

        if self.currentBlockState() == in_state:
            return True
        else:
            return False

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCompleter
from PyQt5 import QtCore

class MyCompleter(QCompleter):
    insertText = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        import sys
        moduls = []
        for i in sys.stdlib_module_names:
            moduls.append(i)
        sit = ['and', 'assert', 'break', 'class', 'continue', 'def',
       'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'exec', 'finally',
       'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import', 'in',
       'is', 'lambda', 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'print',
       'raise', 'return', 'try', 'while', 'yield',
       'None', 'True', 'False']

       for s in sit:
           moduls.append(s)

       QCompleter.__init__(self, moduls, parent)
       self.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.PopupCompletion)
       self.highlighted.connect(self.setHighlighted)

    def setHighlighted(self, text):
        self.lastSelected = text

    def getSelected(self):
        return self.lastSelected
```

Это как компилятор

Comment: Азам, я не знаю откуда вы скопировали приведенный код, но скопировали вы его неправильно. Я по-моему уже отвечал на похожие вопросы, попробуйте поискать. И посмотрите, например, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1342160

Comment: Ник да я видел это тот же код просто я его соединил с подсветкой синтаксиса и у меня почему та пропала нумерация строк